# Persistant view anywhere in the app

Tags: iphone, ios, view, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I'm pretty new to Objective-C and I'm working on a webradio app.

My app is composed of some NavigationControllers included in a TabBarController.

I want to make a View wich would stay just above the TabBar ALL THE TIME. (it will contain the audio player controls and must be accessible anywhere in the app)

What would be the best way to do so?

Thanks!

SQ;p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add your view as a subview of the [UITabBarController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) view property:

```
m_yourToolbar =[[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 401, 320, 44)];
// set some properties on the toolbar
// ...
[self.tabBarController.view m_yourToolbar];
```

This adds the UILabel blah over the content for every tab in the UITabBarController (m_tabBarController).

```
@interface YouAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate, UITabBarControllerDelegate> {
    UIToolbar * m_yourToolbar;

    // ... whatever other stuff you have in your app delegate
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIToolbar * yourToolbar;
```

In your app delegate implementation you will need:

```
@synthesize yourToolbar= m_yourToolbar;
// .. other app delegate stuff
```

So in your view controllers that need to update the toolbar, you can get hold of the app delegate, grab the yourToolbar property and set attributes on it:

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (YouAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
// set stuff on the toolbar property
appDelegate.yourToolbar.stuff = stuff;
```

Comment: +1 This is very common, especially if you want advertisements to show up throughout the app. AdWhirl suggests this exact thing.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. But what is the best way to implement the UITabBarController (there is no .h & .m files for this in the XCode template. the tabBarController is declared in the appDelegate)

Comment: You don't need to implement the UITabBarController. You just need to access the tabBarController declared in the appDelegate (so just replace m_tabBarController with self.tabBarController in your appDelegate code).

Comment: And how can I modify the blah label from anywhere in the app? (from a subview of a navigationController.view for example)

Comment: @SQuat Oh gotcha. You just need to make UILabel * blah a member (and a property) of your app delegate. That you way you can grab the app delegate, then set the text on the blah property from wherever you like. :)

Comment: Sorry about my newbism, but can you explain what I should do exactly to access it?
I replaced the label with a UIToolBar wich have an item on it. How do I change the item's title from "farFromAppDelegateViewController". What should I import to this file, what should I declare... (maybe you could show me some code :)

Comment: @SQuat Hope that edit clarifies how to declare and access properties on the app delegate from other view controllers.